# php cleanup phone variable

Tags: php

Im wanting to record on a database, peoples phone numbers. Since people enter numbers differently(based on area codes) etc, i want to normalize whatever they input into a standard manner before it goes up to a database, then when i read it back from the database and put on the page, that it comes out like this **1-954-999-9999** in this format to which i can then append the `<a href="tel:1-954-999-9999">1-954-999-9999</a>` and can be clicked from the web app / or normal site to make a call.

All this said, i have a question.

On POST this is how im  handling it

```
$compBizNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($c2d, $_POST['compBizNumber']) ;
$compBizNumber = str_replace("(", "-", $compBizNumber);
$compBizNumber = str_replace(")", "-", $compBizNumber);
$compBizNumber = str_replace(" ", "-", $compBizNumber);
$compBizNumber = filter_var($compBizNumber,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;
```

Is there a way to replace multiple characters in one go??

how can i go about this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) accepts an array as the first (and second parameter) so this will do:

```
$compBizNumber = str_replace(array("(", ")", " "), "-", $compBizNumber);
```

However, a more flexible way would be to use a regular expression to replace all non-numeric characters:

```
$compBizNumber = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "-", $compBizNumber);
```

This way you don't have to add all possible characters a user would enter into str_replace.

Comment: Maybe with +#* -> $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/[^+#*0-9]/', '', $phoneNumber);

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regex to remove all except numbers:

```
$myNumber = "+31 (0) 43 - 123 345 67";
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $myNumber);
```

http://codepad.org/30vUqWWC

However, beware of the `+` I guess you'd have to replace that with 00 instead of nothing in order to make the number work? Not 100% sure about that one.